# Event Listeners on iframe not working on Chrome with a hosted domain

Tags: google-chrome, iframe, addeventlistener, event-listener, broadcast-channel

I am trying to pass message from a new window to an iframe on the same origin embedded on a different domain. I tried message passing using Broadcast Channel API, using localStorage with storage event, and shared workers. Nothing is working, bcz of iframe unable to listen to messages.

It's working on localhost, but on hosted on Chrome.
But it's working on both localhost and hosted in OperaGX browser.

Can someone help me with it? If it's a Chrome browser issue, or I have to add a flag in my iframe to make it work for listening messages?